# Nuxt3 dynamic localized route paths

Tags: vue-i18n, nuxt3, nuxt-i18n

As from official documentation (https://v8.i18n.nuxtjs.org/guide/custom-paths and https://v8.i18n.nuxtjs.org/guide/lang-switcher) it seems impossible to have dynamic custom localized route paths with Nuxt3 + i18n.

The only way they suggest is with the compiler macros `defineI18nRoute` and `definePageMeta` and no available composable seem to address this.

To be clear my scenario is with this simple pages structure:

```
articles
--- [category].vue
```

In the `[category].vue` file I fetch articles from apis and I want then to update routing in order for the language switcher to switch to the correct slug.

If for example I navigate to `/en/articles/nice-articles` I want the switcher to switch to `/it/articles/begli-articoli` and not to `/it/articles/nice-articles` as it does by default. The problem is that I can know the `begli-articoli` italian slug only after fetching for the category from the apis.

Does it exist a native workaround that does not imply writing my own switcher?

It seems odd that Nuxt3 + i18n doesn't support this natively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some reading, the closest thing I found to this in the i18n module is [this](https://v8.i18n.nuxtjs.org/guide/lang-switcher#dynamic-route-parameters), but since you get your slugs dynamically from the API as well, this won't work for you, because you'll have to update the dynamic locales inside `definePageMeta` which is a compiler macro, so you can't update it in the runtime.

I think your best bet is to write your own switcher, which should be really simple. Something along the lines of this:

```js
<template>
  ...
  <NuxtLink v-for="locale in availableLocales" :key="locale.code" :to="`/${locale.code}/articles/${articlesLocales[locale.code].slug}`">
    {{ locale.name }}
  </NuxtLink>

  ...
</template>
<script>
  const { locale, locales } = useI18n()
  const availableLocales = computed(() => {
    return (locales.value).filter(i => i.code !== locale.value)
  })

  const { data } = useFetch() // your API fetching logic...

  // change this based on your API strucuture
  const articlesLocales = ref((await data).value.locales)
</script>
```

I do not know how does your API response structure look like but I just assumed there's a `locales` object where keys are locale codes.

Comment: Yes in the end is what I did